# How to send an Android intent from an AOSP library?

Tags: android-intent, android-source

I work on a library directly installed in the Android system, and executed by the AudioFlinger (the android system mediaserver), and build in C++ with the AOSP, *not* with the JNI/NDK. I need to get an event from this library in a classic java application.

Is it possible to send a system intent from my library?

I've tested `am broadcast -a com.myIntent` and it works in the command line but not from inside my library.

**UPDATE:** it IS a permission problem, because activating the permissive mode allow the intent to be catched by my java application. cf
[Sending an intent from c++ to java in Android 5.0.1_r1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910798/sending-an-intent-from-c-to-java-in-android-5-0-1-r1)

Comment: Would [calling `am` sufficient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965444/224671) for you?

Comment: you mean it is possible to send an intent through this command-line, like
system("am broadcast myIntent") ?
I'll try this and update my question if it works :)

Comment: Yes. (Feel free to put that into the answer if it works)

Comment: It is working from the command line:
`C:\>adb shell am broadcast -a com.myIntent
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.myIntent }
Broadcast completed: result=0`
But I can't get it from my C++ with:
`system("am broadcast -a com.myIntent ");`

Comment: Are you running your C++ program as the `shell` user (uid 2000)?

Comment: nope: it is a library executed by the audioflinger (system android mediaserver).

Comment: Ah, perhaps you should add this information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If when you state it works in permissive mode, you mean you have a rooted device and proceed with `adb shell setenforce 0`. Means you have SELinux problem, and will not be allowed by the manufacturer to do that in your library. Even if you modify the SELinux policy in that device, you will most probably have the same problem in many other Android devices in the market.

**EDIT**

If this meets your needs, you can launch that command from within your code. Follow [how to run adb shell commands from android code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731728/how-to-run-adb-shell-commands-from-android-code) on that other matter.

Comment: Indeed, so it is a fix for test, not for production... :(

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to expand it to your needs.

Comment: Did my answer suit your needs?